# How to set plot rendering order in jfree chart

Tags: jfreechart

Whenever you add a subplot to any combinedplot in jfreechart, it adds the new subplot BELOW the previous plot. Is there a simple way to do this or I have to manually reverse the order using a loop?

Comment: Does _below_ mean _y_ or _z_ order?

Comment: The `y` order. Is there a way to override the default Y order after adding subplot?

Comment: Assuming you have a combined plot of some kind, use the `DatasetRenderingOrder` class.

Comment: @Jes: I think `DatasetRenderingOrder` affects _z_ order _within_ a plot, but I'd welcome a counterexample.

Comment: @trashgod you're absolutely right. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Jes: Kudos for researching the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [`CombinedDomainXYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html) for example, the `List` of subplots is implemented as an `ArrayList`, and they are rendered in the order in which they were inserted. To replace a subplot, one simple expedient would be to `remove()` all subplots and add the new entries in the desired order.

Comment: Yeah @trashgod looks like you are right. I checked all possible routs and removing/replacing seems to be only way.